# Laravel in combination with another backend mvc

Tags: php, laravel, yii, laravel-5.3

I want to use laravel and another backend mvc to build a site. Is this possible and if so what would the best way to go about it?

Comment: Did you mean combining Laravel and Yii? that's not possible, i guess.

Comment: The main question si why do you want to do that? You can use laravel with angular, if laravel serves as the api.

Comment: You may try to collect and combine the desired parts of the frameworks and create your own framework configuration.

Comment: I want to use two backend mvc because I want to use crafts cms (yii) with laravel

Comment: In what combination, which purpose would each framework serve in your application, laravel would be the api and craft would pull the data?

Comment: Craft would be the cms and the api and laravel would pull and render the data

Comment: I guess, its not possible.

Comment: you are using laravel as a front end application in the case you mentioned you might want to consider angular or vue to do such tasks. @studiobram

Comment: Is CraftsCMS essential to you as there are quite a few Laravel CMSes out there as well like OctoberCMs or AsgardCMS.

Comment: Unfortunately CraftsCMS essential